# how to make a carousel(sliding) stop when the mouse pointer hovers over on the images

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, gsap

How to make carousel (slider) stop when the mouse pointer has hovered over on the image in GSAP?

I made a huge try in many ways on the internet but nothing suit for my code.

```js
// wrapping the code with onload to execute JS immediately
window.onload = function() {
    //variables for slide animation time
    var slideDelay = 1.2; //the slides flow in every 1.5 seconds
    var slideDuration = 0.2;

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    var prevButton = document.querySelector("#prevButton");
    var nextButton = document.querySelector("#nextButton");

    var numSlides = slides.length;

    //infinite slide rotation

    for (var i = 0; i < numSlides; i++) {
        TweenLite.set(slides[i], {
            xPercent: i * 100
        });
    }

    // auto animation (the timer can be added to auto animate after a certain idle-time)

    var wrap = wrapPartial(-100, (numSlides - 1) * 100);
    var timer = TweenLite.delayedCall(3, autoPlay);

    var animation = TweenMax.to(slides, 1, {
        xPercent: "+=" + (numSlides * 100),
        ease: Linear.easeNone,
        paused: true,
        repeat: -1,
        modifiers: {
            xPercent: wrap
        }
    });

    var proxy = document.createElement("div");
    TweenLite.set(proxy, { x: "+=0" });
    var transform = proxy._gsTransform;
    var slideAnimation = TweenLite.to({}, 0.1, {});
    var slideWidth = 0;
    var wrapWidth = 0;
    resize();

    window.addEventListener("resize", resize);

    // navigation with buttons
    prevButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        animateSlides(1);
    });

    nextButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        animateSlides(-1);
    });

    function animateSlides(direction) {
        timer.restart(true);
        slideAnimation.kill();

        var x = snapX(transform.x + direction * slideWidth);

        slideAnimation = TweenLite.to(proxy, slideDuration, {
            x: x,
            onUpdate: updateProgress
        });
    }

    // auto-play function for auto animation

    function autoPlay() {
        animateSlides(-1);
    }

    function updateProgress() {
        animation.progress(transform.x / wrapWidth);
    }

    function snapX(x) {
        return Math.round(x / slideWidth) * slideWidth;
    }

    //calculating the necessary width for slide animation
    function resize() {
        var norm = (transform.x / wrapWidth) || 0;

        slideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
        wrapWidth = slideWidth * numSlides;

        TweenLite.set(proxy, {
            x: norm * wrapWidth
        });

        animateSlides(0);
        slideAnimation.progress(1);
    }

    //returns the difference between the passed function's max and min value
    function wrapPartial(min, max) {
        var diff = max - min;
        return function(value) {
            var v = value - min;
            return ((diff + v % diff) % diff) + min;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* the main wrapper box */
main {
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 300px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
}

/* the header and navigations */
.controls {
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 60px;
    min-height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

.controls button {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 70%;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: center center;
}

.slides-container {
    border-top: 2px solid ;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

.slide {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 90px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;

    width: 100%;

    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.slides-inner {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>Varshath Gupta Solution</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.20.2/plugins/ModifiersPlugin.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js">
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Main wrapper div for the header and slider components. -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <main>
                <!-- the header that includes the navigation buttons and the logo -->
                <div class="controls">
                    <button id="prevButton" style="background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1o6S3UjO-DQFLXAGShYeN4bQXoI0yuxP0);"></button>
                    <div class="logo"><a href="https://google.com/" target="_blank"><img width="80" src="https://logos.textgiraffe.com/logos/logo-name/Cartoon-designstyle-cartoon-m.png"/></a></div>
                    <button id="nextButton" style="background-image: url( https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1aptD-5krbPTtFRjZk_b2O8Ikx2x0F2TC);"></button>
                </div>
                <!-- the slider -->
                <div class="slides-container">
                    <div class="slides-inner">
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" ><div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1yfm-TD5AphIfhX0dOA_ZEsUjoQlj0VO2)"></div></a>
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" ><div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1QZABQ6aWzXXELWGU-XO9IJECymyfF0oE)"></div></a>
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" ><div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1QxbYIN3XR94dqY29EBzHgpj3_dV0ZqSs)"></div></a>
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url( https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1ngTIZMgHFHTSQO9vinuB666ruA3l-Vgq)"></div></a>
                        <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank" ><div class="slide" style="background-image: url(https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1PBF6K70X3XzhGYuf-myUDPzrSeKwpeJ8)"></div></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that modern JS (okay, not really all that modern anymore, it's been around for ever a decade now) lets you load JS when the DOM is ready with a simple HTML tag attribute. Just use `<script src="..." async defer></script>` in your `<head>` block and done: the file will load independently of your page (due to `async`) and will only _run_ once the DOM is ready for consulting (due to `defer`). No need for `window.onload` or waiting for the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

Comment: See https://greensock.com/mistakes/

Comment: Why would you add garbage like a thousands dots to your question. Please don't do things like that.